# Implementation of SSO system for service provider

Tags: single-sign-on

I am trying to understand implementation of **SSO system** for service provider. Here are my questions.

1. User logs into System A. System A does authentication and displays a link to the user on page. When User clicks the link, System A redirects user to System B where System B is a 3rd party vendor. Who is IdP here and who is SP?
2. Is there any server to server communication in a flow initiated from IdP to SP? Is it required in all scenarios?
3. can you explain the data flow step by step in case of IdP initiated flow to SP?

Any material on this same or simple explanation will help.

Answer (score 0):

In answer to your questions and assuming SSO via Security Markup Language (SAML):

1. System A is the Identity Provider (IdP) and System B is the Service Provider (SP).
2. There is no server-to-server communication. Information is passed via the client browser using HTTP bindings, for example HTTP POST.
3. Step by step IdP-initiated workflow (taken from [OASIS SAML V2.0 Technical Overview](http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/Post2.0/sstc-saml-tech-overview-2.0-cd-02.html#5.1.4.IdP-Initiated%20SSO:%20%20POST%20Binding%7Coutline)):

[image: IdP-Initiated SSO Overview]

> 1. If the user does not have a valid local security context at the IdP, at some point the user will be challenged to supply their credentials to the IdP site, idp.example.org.
> 2. The user provides valid credentials and a local logon security context is created for the user at the IdP.
> 3. The user selects a menu option or link on the IdP to request access to an SP web site, sp.example.com. This causes the IdP's Single Sign-On Service to be called.
> 4. The Single Sign-On Service builds a SAML assertion representing the user's logon security context. Since a POST binding is going to be used, the assertion is digitally signed before it is placed within a SAML  message. The  message is then placed within an HTML FORM as a hidden form control named SAMLResponse. (If the convention for identifying a specific application resource at the SP is supported at the IdP and SP, the resource URL at the SP is also encoded into the form using a hidden form control named RelayState.) The Single Sign-On Service sends the HTML form back to the browser in the HTTP response. For ease-of-use purposes, the HTML FORM typically will contain script code that will automatically post the form to the destination site.
> 5. The browser, due either to a user action or execution of an “auto-submit” script, issues an HTTP POST request to send the form to the SP's Assertion Consumer Service. The service provider's Assertion Consumer Service obtains the  message from the HTML FORM for processing. The digital signature on the SAML assertion must first be validated and then the assertion contents are processed in order to create a local logon security context for the user at the SP. Once this completes, the SP retrieves the RelayState data (if any) to determine the desired application resource URL and sends an HTTP redirect response to the browser directing it to access the requested resource (not shown).
> 6. An access check is made to establish whether the user has the correct authorization to access the resource. If the access check passes, the resource is then returned to the browser.